# Module Federation configuration not generating remoteEntry.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have a legacy app were we are trying to export some components with WP5 module-federation.

The plugin configuration is currently like this:

```
output: {
  filename: "[name].bundle.js",
},
plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "remote",
    filename: "remoteEntry.js",
    remotes: {},
    exposes: {
      "./TestExport": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/TestExport"),
    },
    shared: {
      "react@17": {
        singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
      },
    }
  ),
]
```

the webpack config file is in a `config` dir in the root folder, this is why we are exposing the component with `path.resolve`.

When compiling the code, the `remoteEntry.js` file is not generated and we can't import it in another application using module-federation.

I've tried creating an app and exporting something with module-federation and consuming it inside the legacy app and it worked, but the opposite doesn't work.

Comment: have u found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

You have to modilfy some of the configurations in your angular.json file. Hope you already figured the solution.